# How to use 'sortvar' while generating forest plots using meta in R?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, forest-plot

I am running into an error if I attempt to sort forest plot output by my outcome values using `sortvar`. If I just enter the outcome variable name, I get `'object not found'`. Alternatively if I try entering `data$varname`, I get a warning `sortvar is not a graphical parameter`. For example,

`m1_meta <- rma(txgap_sine, V2, data = data, method = "REML")`

And for the forest plot: `Error: 'object not found'`

```
meta::forest(m1_meta, sortvar = txgap_sine, refline = 0.5,
transf = transf.ipft.hm, targs = list(ni = data$denominator),
addfit = FALSE, slab = paste(data$Disorder_name, data$country), cex = 1.2)
```

Alternatively, if I use `data$txgap_sine`, I get the warning `'sortvar is not a graphical parameter'`.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: You might be better on https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where questions about meta-analysis in R are on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `rma` object, so you are in fact calling `metafor:::forest.rma` which is `forest` from the `metafor` package. This is the [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metafor/versions/2.4-0/topics/forest.rma) manual you need or you can type `?metafor:::forest.rma`. The argument is `order=` and I use an example below:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
m1_meta <- rma(yi, vi, data = dat, method = "REML")

forest(m1_meta)
```

[image]

Now you provide the order to plot, this is in increasing order:

```
forest(m1_meta,order=order(dat$yi))
```

[image]